# ionic 3 - cannot install mixpanel plugin for ios using latest xcode

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic3, ionic-native

I executed

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

The error below occurred, I spend all day but I was not able to find the solution.

```
apple-ios version check failed ("D:\Ionic\Jobtivity\MobileAppTesting1.1\platforms\ios\cordova\apple_ios_version"), continuing anyways.
Installing "cordova-plugin-mixpanel" for ios
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-mixpanel': CordovaError: Uh oh!
Cannot find resource file "D:\Ionic\Jobtivity\MobileAppTesting1.1\plugins\cordova-plugin-mixpanel\src\ios\Mixpanel\.DS_Store" for plugin cordova-plugin-mixpanel in iOS platform
    at install (D:\Ionic\Jobtivity\MobileAppTesting1.1\platforms\ios\cordova\lib\plugman\pluginHandlers.js:61:23)
    at ActionStack.process (D:\Ionic\Jobtivity\MobileAppTesting1.1\platforms\ios\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\ActionStack.js:56:25)
    at PluginManager.doOperation (D:\Ionic\Jobtivity\MobileAppTesting1.1\platforms\ios\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\PluginManager.js:114:20)
    at PluginManager.addPlugin (D:\Ionic\Jobtivity\MobileAppTesting1.1\platforms\ios\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\PluginManager.js:144:17)
    at Api.addPlugin (D:\Ionic\Jobtivity\MobileAppTesting1.1\platforms\ios\cordova\Api.js:234:10)
    at handleInstall (C:\Users\Satya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:594:10)
    at C:\Users\Satya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:357:28
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Satya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
    at C:\Users\Satya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Satya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
Uh oh!
Cannot find resource file "D:\Ionic\Jobtivity\MobileAppTesting1.1\plugins\cordova-plugin-mixpanel\src\ios\Mixpanel\.DS_Store" for plugin cordova-plugin-mixpanel in iOS platform
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem. It's related to the current version of the mixpanel plugin (4.6.0). More info [here](https://github.com/samzilverberg/cordova-mixpanel-plugin/issues/100#issuecomment-478994489)

The solution is to install a previous version of that plugin. You have to remove the current one (just to be safe):

```
rm -Rf plugins\cordova-plugin-mixpanel
```

(or delete the folder however you want). And then install version 4.5.2:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mixpanel@4.5.2
```